# Computer freezes after fresh install

Tags: windows-7, freeze, fresh-install

After a lot of use my computer has started to freeze, I did a fresh install of Windows 7 and the problem persists, sometimes the computer freezes and i have to shut it down, I´ve tried to install linux and it works fine with it but with windows it doesn`t. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but by "fresh install" you mean you didn't install anything apart from the operating system, right? As in, you had this problem as soon as the computer rebooted and you started using the applications present in the default install?

Comment: Also, have you tried doing a complete install while disconnected from all networks, and seen if the problem still persists? It could be a Windows-specific worm on your LAN.

Comment: did you started to chek your pc health status? memory, hard disk.... benchmarks?

Answer (score 1):

Hard problem without having the machine to look at. If linux doesn't freeze that most likely rules out a hardware problem. Try and cntrl alt delete > task manager > processes sort by cpu usage and see if anything is acting crazy right before the pc freezes. There could be some program causing it to freeze. If that is not the issue it is most likely a problem with the hard drive, specifically the partition you keep putting windows on. When a computer freezes it usually means that is can no longer access the drive with the os.

Comment: Could it be a malware issue that perpetuated even through the OS reinstallation? You might try formatting the HD *completely* (on another PC or booting from Linux), and *then* reinstalling Windows.